# Swift how to reference an image file that is not in *.xcassets folder in storyboard

Tags: swift, uiimage, xcode-storyboard, launch-screen

I was trying to update the icon of my app in LaunchScreen, turned out that the UIImage doesn't update for the situation that a user update from old version to new version, and I searched on web for some solutions, there is one suggesting that I should load image files that are out of the *.xcassets folder, I know how to put the image files to my project root directory, but I don't know how to load it in storyboard, as LaunchScreen.storyboard can't have a view controller class

So my question is: How to reference image files in storyboard

This is the source link: http://arsenkin.com/launch_screen_image_cache.html

Comment: If you just add an image file to your project, what do you see under the attributes inspector?  If you see that image file under the attributes inspector, you can access it merely with `UIImage(named:)`.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use any custom behavior in `LaunchScreen.storyboard`. And loading images from anywhere except *.xcassets is a custom behavior.

Generally you'd use something like

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "image", ofType: "imageType")
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path!)
```

to load such an image, but as I've already mentioned, this approach doesn't work for launch screens

Comment: `Bundle`?  Access it with `UIImage(named:)`.

Comment: @ElTomato UIImage(named:) works when you load an image from assets catalogue. The question refers to an image file stored somewhere in the project, e.g. project root folder.

Comment: Okay.  I've got that.  So?